# yaml-cpp Easiest way to iterate through a map with undefined values

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I'd like to obtain every node in a map without knowing the keys.

My YAML looks like this:

```
characterType :
 type1 :
  attribute1 : something
  attribute2 : something
 type2 :
  attribute1 : something
  attribute2 : something
```

I don't know how many "type"s will be declared or what the name of those keys will be. That's why I'm trying to iterate through the map.

```
struct CharacterType{
  std::string attribute1;
  std::string attribute2;
};

namespace YAML{
  template<>
  struct convert<CharacterType>{
    static bool decode(const Node& node, CharacterType& cType){ 
       cType.attribute1 = node["attribute1"].as<std::string>();
       cType.attribute2 = node["attribute2"].as<std::string>();
       return true;
    }
  };
}

---------------------
std::vector<CharacterType> cTypeList;

for(YAML::const_iterator it=node["characterType"].begin(); it != node["characterType"].end(); ++it){
   cTypeList.push_back(it->as<CharacterType>());
}
```

The previous code doesn't give any trouble when compiling but then at execution time I get this error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of `YAML::TypedBadConversion<CharacterType>`

I've also tried using a subindex instead of the iterator, getting the same error.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, I just can't see it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you iterate through a map, the iterator points to a key/value pair of nodes, not a single node. For example:

```
YAML::Node characterType = node["characterType"];
for(YAML::const_iterator it=characterType.begin();it != characterType.end();++it) {
   std::string key = it->first.as<std::string>();       // <- key
   cTypeList.push_back(it->second.as<CharacterType>()); // <- value
}
```

(The *reason* that your code compiled, even though your node is a map node, is that `YAML::Node` is effectively dynamically typed, so its iterator has to act (statically) as both a sequence iterator and a map iterator.)

Comment: A bit offtopic, but I’d find it nice to have a way to get whole map (YAML structure) out as a string, I can’t seem to find any API document where such possibility are mentioned.

Comment: Also looks like if the value is empty, this error will be raised, instead of returning empty string...

Comment: @Smar, check out the Emitter.

Comment: @jesseBeder I wanted to just get the string for quick debugging instead of constructing something for it myself, but yeah, that could be used for it I guess :)

Comment: @Smar, look at YAML::Dump as a shorthand.

Comment: To anyone wondering, the official tutorial documentation to show this is here: https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial#basic-parsing-and-node-editing See the `YAML::Node lineup` example under the "Basic Parsing and Node Editing" section.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @jesse-beder is right, I give just another option with using range-based for loop like below:

```
for(const auto& characterType : node["characterType"]) {
   std::string key = characterType.first.as<std::string>();
   cTypeList.push_back(characterType.second.as<CharacterType>());
}
```