# can run C++ code from command line but not from debug mode in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I compiled the program below in debug mode without any error. I could run .exe file from the command line but when I try to debug code inside visual studio the exception gets thrown from the line

```
DetectionInternalSettings* internal_settings =
           DetectionInternalSettingsFactory::createFromFileSystem(
                  "C:/data/card_detection_engine.yaml");
```

Anyone who faced this situation before where behavior is different running from command line and in debug mode.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    DetectionSettings settings;
    try
    {
        DetectionInternalSettings* internal_settings =
        DetectionInternalSettingsFactory::createFromFileSystem("../data/card_detection_engine.yaml");
    }
    catch (const MyException &e)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Exception raised: %s\n", e.what().c_str());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I also went into the exception details and here it is First-chance exception at 0x76E1C41F in ocrcarddetectionengine_sample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: YAML::TypedBadConversion at memory location 0x003FF0D0.

More code related to `createFromFileSystem`

```
DetectionInternalSettingsFactory::createFromFileSystem(const std::string &configPath)  throw (MyException)
{
  return new DetectionInternalSettingsImpl(configPath);
}

struct DetectionInternalSettingsImpl : public DetectionInternalSettings {
    DetectionInternalSettingsImpl(const std::string &config_path) {
        if (config.ReadFromFilesystem(config_path)) {
            throw MyException("Bad configuration path.");
        }
    }

    ~DetectionInternalSettingsImpl() { }

    Core::Detector::Configuration config;
};
```

Comment: Show us `createFromFileSystem` and tell us what the exception is...

Comment: Running a program from the command line vs the IDE, you have different heaps, and different CWDs.  I suspect the CWD is the issue.

Comment: Ed S. I have put more code in the question above

Comment: Are you linking to an outside library ? Have you tweaked Visual Studio's project configuration parameters between your last complete Make process and the last partial compilation ?

Comment: the exception comes from config.ReadFromFilesystem, and it is YAML::TypedBadConversion - have you debugged into ReadFromFilesystem to see where the exception raised? it is probably type conversion error as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374691/yaml-cpp-easiest-way-to-iterate-through-a-map-with-undefined-values suggests

Comment: But why is not happening when I run from command line. I even reads out the contents of the yaml correctly and then processes that input.

Comment: That is yet to be figured out - as @MooingDuck mentioned, it might be the CWD, it might be the parameters you configured in VS for debugging. Since you have the code, and you know the exception, why not start debugging as a start - then maybe we will have a better idea.

Comment: Yes it was the CWD guys. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @vkaul11 good to know you fixed it - could you explain a bit how CWD cause the YAML::TypedBadConversion? thanks

Comment: The problem was that "../data/card_detection_engine.yaml" does not seem to not pick the right path "../data/card_detection_engine.yaml" when run from the debugger but when I run the .exe from command line it uses the right project directory. Therefore I used "C:/data/card_detection_engine.yaml" to give the absolute path, but even that failed with the debugger. That was fixed with "C://data//card_detection_engine.yaml" double slash.

Answer (score 0):

Trust the debug mode exception. It is testing more thoroughly what your code is actually doing while the command line is simply waiting for problems to happen.

In your case, they don't seem to happen, probably because you're not doing anything with the pointer variable.